# PrincipalContext::ValidateCredentials throws LdapException with invalid password

Tags: visual-c++, active-directory, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

I have a windows application, which is trying to validate a user / password on Active Directory with the following code.

```
PrincipalContext^ pc = gcnew PrincipalContext(ContextType::Domain);
// validate the credentials
bool isValid = pc->ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
if(!isValid)
{
    throw gcnew SecurityTokenValidationException("Invalid user ID / password");
}

UserPrincipal^ upUser = UserPrincipal::FindByIdentity(pc, userName);
if(upUser && !upUser->IsMemberOf(pc, IdentityType::SamAccountName, ADGroup))
{
    String^ msg = "User " + userName + " is not a member of the " + ADGroup + " group.";
    throw gcnew SecurityTokenValidationException(msg);
}
```

When running this code under a Visual Studio 2008 / .NET 3.5 / 32 bit build, if I give a valid user but invalid passwordd, ValidateCredentials() returns false.

Using a Visual Studio 2013 / .NET 4.0 / 64 bit build, the exact same code throws an LdapException:

```
System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException: The LDAP server is unavailable.
at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.Connect()
at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.BindHelper(NetworkCredential newCredential, Boolean needSetCredential)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.CredentialValidator.lockedLdapBind(LdapConnection current, NetworkCredential creds, ContextOptions contextOptions)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.CredentialValidator.BindLdap(NetworkCredential creds, ContextOptions contextOptions)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.CredentialValidator.Validate(String userName, String password)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials(String userName, String password)
at soapcon.ADUserNameValidator.Validate(String userName, String password)
```

If I disconnect my PC from the network, I get a `PrincipalServerDownException` exception, so I'm pretty sure that I am actually talking to our AD server.

Is this a problem with my code, an issue with .NET or possibly due to our exceedingly old Active Directory Service setup (Windows 2000)?

Comment: That is not `c#` but `c++ .net`. BTW, is the application pool being executed under a domain acount in the IIS config? IIS behaves different than Cassiny

Comment: @bradbury9 I'm not running IIS,it's just a windows application, running under my developer domain account.

Comment: I wonder if different frameworks would use different default authentication options, could you try the `.ValidateCredentials (String, String, ContextOptions)` overload in both cases?

Comment: @bradbury9 Do you want to add this comment as an answer? Using a ContextOptions  of 'ContextOptions::Negotiate | ContextOptions::Signing | ContextOptions::Sealing;' seems to fix my issue.

Comment: Done, glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if different frameworks would use different default authentication options, could you try the `.ValidateCredentials (String, String, ContextOptions)` overload in both cases?

As per comment, try this `ContextOptions` flags in the overload:

```
ContextOptions::Negotiate | ContextOptions::Signing | ContextOptions::Sealing
```